# How do i do some search feature like this

Tags: 7, views, search

I have a requirement like this show in image
[image]

Like left hand side i need to show some fields data and when i click on the links i should filter out the data in content area. and its should be like a AND operation ? I need to use VIEWS and what else modules are needed for this thing to be completed?

Comment: Should items on the left hand side be taxonomy terms ?

Comment: It will be some node reference texts in one section and some taxonomy terms. If it can be done using taxonomy completely i can change it.

Comment: Most probably the keyword here is "faceted search". Are you looking for such a solution ? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faceted_search)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to the issue on D7 Faceted Search module [here](http://drupal.org/node/898612).

Using specialized search systems (**Solr**, Sphinx, Xapian, or others) is the way to go.

You can get results with [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), the [Apache Solr Search Integration](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) module, and customizations.

Comment: can i make this work without using Solr i.e. just by using drupal DB ?

Comment: Try http://drupal.org/project/faceted_search on D6. This is not for D7.

Comment: For Solr you need access via ssh and to be able to install java and solr packages. You don't need a separate mysql database. If you prefer, you can use Solr search offered as a service http://www.acquia.com/products-services/acquia-search.

Comment: you mean to say that with out solr on D7 faceted wont work?

Comment: I mean drupal.org/project/faceted_search project doesn't work on D7.

Comment: @ refineo - yup saw that and they have no idea of porting it to D7 also